# Duplicate documents in lucene.net index

Tags: c#, wpf, lucene, lucene.net

I am using lucene.net to index my pdf files. after refreshing index it will show same documnet multiple times (= Number of time I refresh my index).

I am using latest version of lucene.net indexing (Lucene.net 3.0.3).

Here is my code for indexing.

```
public void refreshIndexes()  
    {
        // Create Index Writer
        string strIndexDir = @"Z:\Munavvar\LuceneTest\index";
        IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir)), new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);

        writer.DeleteAll();
        // Find all files in root folder create index on them
        List<string> lstFiles = searchFiles(@"Z:\Munavvar\LuceneTest\PDFs");
        foreach (string strFile in lstFiles)
        {
            Document doc = new Document();
            string FileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(strFile);
            string Text = ExtractTextFromPdf(strFile);
            string Path = strFile;
            string ModifiedDate = Convert.ToString(File.GetLastWriteTime(strFile));
            string DocumentType = string.Empty;
            string Vault = string.Empty;

            string headerText = Text.Substring(0, Text.Length < 150 ? Text.Length : 150);
            foreach (var docs in ltDocumentTypes)
            {
                if (headerText.ToUpper().Contains(docs.searchText.ToUpper()))
                {
                    DocumentType = docs.DocumentType;
                    Vault = docs.VaultName; ;
                }
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(DocumentType))
            {
                DocumentType = "Default";
                Vault = "Default";
            }

            doc.Add(new Field("filename", FileName, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("text", Text, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("path", Path, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("modifieddate", ModifiedDate, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("documenttype", DocumentType, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));
            doc.Add(new Field("vault", Vault, Field.Store.YES, Field.Index.ANALYZED));

            writer.AddDocument(doc);
        }
        writer.Optimize();
        writer.Dispose();
    }
```

Here is my index searcing code

```
public List<IndexDocument> searchFromIndexes(string searchText)
    {
        try
        {
            #region search in indexes and fill list
            // Create list
            List<IndexDocument> searchResult = new List<IndexDocument>();

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchText))
            {
                string strIndexDir = @"Z:\Munavvar\LuceneTest\index";
                var analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_30);
                IndexSearcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir)));

                // parse the query, "text" is the default field to search
                Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser parser = new Lucene.Net.QueryParsers.QueryParser(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29, "text", analyzer);


                Query query = parser.Parse(searchText);

                // search
                TopDocs hits = searcher.Search(query, searcher.MaxDoc);

                // showing first TotalHits results
                for (int i = 0; i < hits.TotalHits; i++)
                {
                    // get the document from index
                    Document doc = searcher.Doc(hits.ScoreDocs[i].Doc);

                    // create a new row with the result data
                    searchResult.Add(new IndexDocument()
                        {
                            FileName = doc.Get("filename"),
                            Text = doc.Get("text"),
                            Path = doc.Get("path"),
                            ModifiedDate = doc.Get("modifieddate"),
                            Vault = doc.Get("vault"),
                            DocumentType = doc.Get("documenttype"),
                        });

                }
                searcher.Dispose();
            }
            return searchResult;
            #endregion

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
    }
```

---

**UPDATE**

> I have one button on window that call **refreshIndexes** method.
>
> It will clear old index when I close and again run application and click that button

Comment: That's because, you need to delete the previous data. By the way, what is `ltDocumentTypes`

Comment: @RichaGarg - The third argument to the `IndexWriter` ctor specifies whether the existing index (if there is one) should be overwritten or appended to.  It being `true`, the old index *should* be deleted.

Comment: Can you provide some information on how you are searching this index?  One thing I'm wondering, is if it's possible you could be keeping old readers open somewhere.  Seems like you would have to be collecting them in a `MultiReader` or something, though...

Comment: Sure. Edited.. please check question again for searching index code

Comment: it must be a problem with indexing data.. Becuase even after restaring the app it shows duplicate documents data.

Comment: @femtoRgon, Thanks for sharing :)

Comment: is it problem of garbage objects? just curious

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Come up with a solution.

Problem:
I am calling refreshIndexes method from global class object.

```
VaultIndexes vIndexes = new VaultIndexes();
private void btnRefreshIndex_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    vIndexes.refreshIndexes();
}
```

Solution:
Creat new object object every time.

```
private void btnRefreshIndex_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    VaultIndexes vIndexes = new VaultIndexes();
    vIndexes.refreshIndexes();
}
```

> I dont know why it is creating duplicate documents with global class
>   object.
>
> As @RichaGarg state in comment, it must not create new document
>   according to 3rd argument of IndexWriter

```
IndexWriter writer = new IndexWriter(Lucene.Net.Store.FSDirectory.Open(new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(strIndexDir)), new StandardAnalyzer(Lucene.Net.Util.Version.LUCENE_29), true, IndexWriter.MaxFieldLength.UNLIMITED);
```